Not getting new line after pasting table from outside lexical rich text editor
i am using lexical rich text editor with table and i am facing issue while pasting table from outside. this issue is from library but still am not able to file way that how to achieve it
for ref: new line achieved while creating table like this:
export function TablePlugin({
    cellEditorConfig,
    children,
}: {
    cellEditorConfig: CellEditorConfig;
    children: JSX.Element | Array<JSX.Element>;
}): JSX.Element | null {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    const cellContext = useContext(CellContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!editor.hasNodes([TableNode])) {
            invariant(false, 'TablePlugin: TableNode is not registered on editor');
        }

        cellContext.set(cellEditorConfig, children);

        return editor.registerCommand<InsertTableCommandPayload>(
            INSERT_TABLE_COMMAND,
            ({ columns, rows, includeHeaders }) => {
                const selection = $getSelection();

                if (!$isRangeSelection(selection)) {
                    return true;
                }

                const focus = selection.focus;
                const focusNode = focus.getNode();

                if (focusNode !== null) {
                    const tableNode = $createTableNodeWithDimensions(Number(rows), Number(columns), includeHeaders);

                    if ($isRootOrShadowRoot(focusNode)) {
                        const target = focusNode.getChildAtIndex(focus.offset);

                        if (target !== null) {
                            target.insertBefore(tableNode);
                        } else {
                            focusNode.append(tableNode);
                        }

                        tableNode.insertBefore($createParagraphNode());
                    } else {
                        const topLevelNode = focusNode.getTopLevelElementOrThrow();
                        topLevelNode.insertAfter(tableNode);
                    }
//inserting new line here
                    tableNode.insertAfter($createParagraphNode());
                    const nodeSelection = $createNodeSelection();
                    nodeSelection.add(tableNode.getKey());
                    $setSelection(nodeSelection);
                }

                return true;
            },
            COMMAND_PRIORITY_EDITOR,
        );
    }, [cellContext, cellEditorConfig, children, editor]);

    return null;
}

but i am not sure how to achieve for copy paste
i have tried to make a plugin like above but not worked for me

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite JavaScript?Java?Rust?C#? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

git the answer
make a custom paste plugin

export default function PasteLogPlugin(): JSX.Element {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        return editor.registerCommand(
            PASTE_COMMAND,
            (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
                const { clipboardData } = e;
                const concreteData = clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
                if (!concreteData) return;
            
                const pastedContent = concreteData.getData('text/html'); // Get HTML content
                
                const parsedContent = new DOMParser().parseFromString(pastedContent, 'text/html');
                const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, parsedContent);
                const tableNode = nodes[0];
                const selection = $getSelection();
                if (!$isRangeSelection(selection)) {
                    return;
                }
                const focus = selection.focus;
                const focusNode = focus.getNode();
                if (focusNode !== null && $isTableNode(tableNode)) {
                    // focusNode.select();

                    // $insertNodes([...nodes, $createParagraphNode()]);
                    if ($isRootOrShadowRoot(focusNode)) {
                        const target = focusNode.getChildAtIndex(focus.offset);

                        if (target !== null) {
                            target.insertBefore(tableNode);
                        } else {
                            focusNode.append(tableNode);
                        }

                        tableNode.insertBefore($createParagraphNode());
                    } else {
                        const topLevelNode = focusNode.getTopLevelElementOrThrow();
                        topLevelNode.insertAfter(tableNode);
                    }
                    const lastParagraph = $createParagraphNode();
                    tableNode.insertAfter(lastParagraph);
                    const nodeSelection = $createNodeSelection();
                    nodeSelection.add(tableNode.getNextSibling().getKey());
                    $setSelection(nodeSelection);
                } else return false;
                return true;
            },
            COMMAND_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
        );
    }, [editor]);

    return null;
}

and use this plugin inside your editor
